# Paste yanked text in several sequential lines

Tags: vim, copy-paste

If I have multi-line line snippet:

```
length = 1;
keys = NewKey(value);
gt_backref = NULL;   
ls_backref = NULL;
```

And I need to paste yanked (`<ctrl>-V+y`) `node->` between every line of snippet:

```
node->length = 1;
node->keys = NewKey(value);
node->gt_backref = NULL;   
node->ls_backref = NULL;
```

How do I paste yanked text in several sequential lines?  Something like `<ctrl>-V+<shift>-I` but for paste, not for typed text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<C-v>{motion}I<C-r>"<Esc>
```

1. Enter visual block mode with `<C-v>`.
2. Extend your selection.
3. Hit `I` to enter insert mode.
4. Do `<C-r>"` to insert the content of the unnamed register.
5. Hit `<Esc>` to apply the change to all the selected lines.

Or with `:normal`:

```
:[range]norm I<C-r>"<CR>
```

Comment: I'll just add that from any inserted mode you can always use <C-r>" to paste. You can also use <C-r>* to paste from general clipboard.

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to understand for me this denotation. What is <C-r>? Is it ctrl+r or shift+c(upper C)+r or just ctrl?

Comment: `<C-r>` is `Ctrl+R`. See `:help key-notation`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you select the text with Shift-V, then do a regex

```
:'<,'>s/.*/node->&/
```

that would add node-> to the selected lines.

or I guess even simpiler

```
:'<,'>s/^/node->/
```

If it's more complicated, maybe you would create some kind of macro with a search to find the type of lines you want to replace and run the same regex replace on each of those lines

Answer (score 0):

This answer based on @Shaun's answer. This really needs a macro. But the correct regexp is

```
:'<,'>s/\(^\s\+\)/\1node->/
```

Because I need to take into account indentation.
But this approach does not universal. For every particular case we need new regexp.